# TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I want delete user and his phones.

```
 var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://10.28.16.199:7474/db/data"));
                client.Connect();
                client.Cypher
                    .Match("(user:User)-[r]->(phone:Phone)")
                    .Where((Users user) => user.Fio == name)
                    .Delete("r,user")
                    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Its show me error TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably other relationships still attached to the user. You need to delete all of them too.